# How to prevent automated overwriting of files , or how to add (1) and (2) to duplicate files instead of overwriting

Tags: batch-file, overwrite

I have created a batch file that will run on an FTP server. There is a camera that saves files in the format xxxxNG.txt and xxxxOK.txt in C:\images\0000. The script I wrote renames the files with the current time and date and moves them to an OK or NG folder elsewhere depending on the original file name.

This works well, however if there are multiple images to process at once, the program names them all the same thing and overwrites until there aren't any more, leaving only the last one.

Here's what I have so far:

```
rem This is a simple script to move images from the FTP save location to the 
backup location (here)

echo off
cls
:again
@echo off
cls

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "dateandtime=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

echo The current time is: %dateandtime%
echo.
echo Moving new files...

rem if exist %dateandtime%*.txt (


for /r "C:\test\Images" %%x in (*OK.txt) do move "%%x" C:\test\OK\" "%dateandtime%_OK.txt"

for /r "C:\test\Images" %%x in (*NG.txt) do move "%%x" C:\test\NG\" "%dateandtime%_NG.txt"

echo New files have been renamed and moved.
echo.
echo Checking for old files...

forfiles -p "C:\test\OK" -s -m *.* -d -1 -c "cmd /c del /Q @path"
forfiles -p "C:\test\NG" -s -m *.* -d -1 -c "cmd /c del /Q @path"

echo Files older than 5 years have been deleted.
echo.

timeout /t 1 /nobreak 

goto again

echo done
```

How do I get it to name files processed at the same time to not overwrite and have different names? I tried a method checking if the file already exists, but I'm not sure how to modify the for /r "C:\test\Images" %%x in (*OK.txt) do move "%%x" C:\test\OK\" "%dateandtime%_OK.txt" line to accommodate this. I'm trying something like

```
for /r "C:\test\Images" %%x in (*OK.txt) do move "%%x" C:\test\OK\" "%dateandtime%-%foo%_OK.txt"
```

but the %foo% breaks it. I thought I understood foo as the iteration of the for loop. is there an equivalent in the do loop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't the simple solution be to get the date and time before you rename each file instead of getting it just once at the top of your script? This way a new seconds will be used for each file.

Comment: As above, effectively `call`ing the dateandtime creation as a function and using delayed expansion for dynamic updating of the variable. _If the `call` routine takes less than a second to run, a `timeout` could easily force its hand_

Comment: Or maybe a better solution would be to rename the files with the original file name with the date and time appended to the end of the file name.

Comment: Where did you ever see documentation that says `FOO` is the `FOR` commands iteration within the LOOP.  That makes no sense considering you are using `%%x`.  The meta-variable you define within the `FOR` command is the iteration.

Comment: didn't know, `move` accepts three parameters...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the easiest way to fix your current issue is to use the original file name and append the time stamp to the original file name.

```
for /r "C:\test\Images" %%G in (*OK.txt) do move "%%G" "C:\test\OK\%%~nG-%dateandtime%%%~xG"
```

I use upper case letters for my FOR meta-variable so that it does not cause any confusion as to what command modifier is being used.

So if your input file names are:

```
1234OK.txt
7890OK.txt
```

They will be moved and renamed to:

```
1234OK-20180314104211.txt
7890OK-20180314104211.txt
```